# Как подсчитать именно сколько линий имеют негативные числа, а не само количество чисел?

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

У меня программа просто подсчитывает количество негативных элементов, а мне нужно чтоб подсчитало количество рядков в которых нет негативных элементов.
Тоесть я ввожу 9 элементов для массива, к примеру 8 -2 6 9 -3 -1 12 2 1, так как у меня размерность массива 3*3, то в результате я должен получить цифру 1, так как в рядке 12 2 1, нет не единого негативного числа.

```
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    const int N=3, M=3;
    int i, j , mas[N][M];
    int count=0;
    printf("Input %d elements: ",N*M);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++)
    for (j=0; j<M; j++) {
        scanf("%d", &mas[i][j]);
        if (mas[i][j] < 0)
        count++;
    }
    printf("Result = %d", count);
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заведите два счетчика. Один будет считать кол-во отрицательных чисел в строке, а второй - кол-во строк, по итогам проверки которых первый счетчик остался равен нулю.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    const int N=3, M=3;
    int i, j , mas[N][M], tmp;
    int count=0;
    printf("Input %d elements: ",N*M);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        tmp=0;    
        for (j=0; j<M; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &mas[i][j]);
            if (mas[i][j] < 0) tmp++;
        }
        if (tmp==0) count++;
    }
    printf("Result = %d", count);
    return 0; 
}
```

```
Input 9 elements: 8 -2 6 9 -3 -1 12 2 1
Result = 1
```